# How come I can't writeUTF to RMS?

Tags: java, java-me, rms

I am developing an app using J2ME.
The project is to store integer and string data into RMS.

The error shows that `out.writeUTF(i.getNumberPlate());` is not working.

So any solution to solve this problem? The compiler cant even compile the project.

```
public class CarparkReservationParser {
    public static byte[] parseObj(CarparkReservation i) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream out;

        try {

            out = new DataOutputStream(baos);

            // write into string
            out.writeInt(i.getCarpark());
            out.writeUTF(i.getNumberPlate());
            out.writeUTF(i.getStudentID());
            out.writeUTF(i.getName());
            out.writeInt(i.getYear());
            out.writeInt(i.getMonth());

            // baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        // convert to byte array
        return baos.toByteArray();

    }
}
```

Comment: It would probably help if you told us what errors the compiler gives.

Comment: Take a look at the return type of `getNumberPlate()`—it may not return a `String`, which is the type that `writeUTF` requires.

Answer (score 0):

@jack's comment is right. [`writeUTF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/cldc1.1/jsr139/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) receives a String as parameter. If `getNumberPlate()` does not return a `String` you must change your code. For example:

```
out.writeUTF(i.getNumberPlate().toString());
```